# Which database takes up more disk space MongoDB or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have a large database in MongoDB volume of 25gb, because of complex queries aggregation MongoDB cope worse than MySQL, but there is a fear that MySQL will take much more space on disk, is there any way to know the approximate size of the database but in MySQL? Perhaps someone has already done a comparison of these databases in terms of size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on a lot of choices specific to your database, such as:

- MongoDB storage engine
- MySQL storage engine
- Number of indexes
- Data types of indexed and non-indexed columns
- Compression options used in either brand of database
- Probably other factors

The best way to get an accurate comparison is to try it yourself using your data and your data model.

See also my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66873904/20860